# typescript node cannot find module

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, definitelytyped

trying to publish some project's types ( call it payouts-api) to another project-main

I'm getting `Cannot find module` Error.

When compiling the project, everything is compiled successfully
but when running mocha I'm getting `Cannot find module 'payouts-api'`.

payouts-api dist structure:
[image]

that's my payouts-api's package.json
i only publish the dist folder

```
{
   "name": "payouts-api",
   "version": "1.0.15",
   "description": "",
   "main": "src/index.js",
   "types": "./types/payouts-api.d.ts",
   "files": [
      "/dist"
   ],
   "scripts": {
      "clean": "rm -rf ./dist/* ",
      "build": "tsc && npm run copyfiles",
      "start": "node ./dist/src/index.js",
      "lint": "tslint src/**/*",
      "serve": "ts-node ./src/index.ts",
      "create-declarations": "dts-generator --project ./ --out ./types/payouts-api.d.ts  --verbose",
      "copyfiles": "copyfiles -u 1 src/api.yaml dist/src",
      "start:dev": "nodemon",
      "test": "tsc -p . && mocha dist/tests/unit-tests/**/*-spec.js --recursive",
      "test:coverage": "tsc -p . && nyc npm test"
   },
   "author": "",
   "dependencies": {
      "@types/mocha": "^5.2.7",
      <more dependencies....>
   },

}
```

in project main :
when running mocha, when it tries to consume the payouts-api package 
I get: `Error: Cannot find module 'payouts-api/dist/types/src/database/entities/BankAccount'`

the way I'm trying to consume is:
`import { BankAccountStatus } from 'payouts-api/dist/types/src/database/entities/BankAccount';`

Comment: should it be relative import e.g. `import { ... } from '../../src/database/entities/BankAccount`?

Comment: @deerawan in non relative import oit didnt work